# ld: warning: directory not found for option -- deleting derived data and cleaning project don't work

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

I moved the entire folder for the app I'm working on in Xcode from one place to another on my computer and got the warning `ld: warning: directory not found for option` followed by a long path.

I followed the accepted answer at [Apple Mach-O Linker errors and I don't know what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706348/apple-mach-o-linker-errors-and-i-dont-know-what-to-do) but still got the same warning.

**EDIT:** Here's the message I get, in case it's relevant:

```
Ld /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaikuTabbed-aszefnihmscxaachdbimtmeozapo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GayHaikuTabbed.app/GayHaikuTabbed normal i386
cd /Users/joel/Development/GayHaiku
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaikuTabbed-aszefnihmscxaachdbimtmeozapo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/joel/Development/GayHaiku/GayHaikuTabbed -L/Users/joel/Development/GayHaiku -F/Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaikuTabbed-aszefnihmscxaachdbimtmeozapo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F. -FGayHaikuTabbed -FGayHaikuTabbedTests -F/Users/joel/Development/GayHaiku -F/Users/joel/Development/GayHaiku/../../../Downloads -F/Users/joel/Development/GayHaiku/../../Downloads -filelist /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaikuTabbed-aszefnihmscxaachdbimtmeozapo/Build/Intermediates/GayHaikuTabbed.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GayHaikuTabbed.build/Objects-normal/i386/GayHaikuTabbed.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework Parse -framework Accounts -framework AdSupport -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework Twitter -lsqlite3 -lz -lz.1.1.3 -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework Social -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -o /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaikuTabbed-aszefnihmscxaachdbimtmeozapo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GayHaikuTabbed.app/GayHaikuTabbed

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/joel/Development/GayHaiku/../../../Downloads'
```

**EDIT:**  Turns out that cleaning the project removes the warning--but only until I build it again, and then the warning appears again.  I've also tried deleting the derived data, but nothing doing.  :(

**EDIT:**  Well, the library search paths and header search paths are empty, but there are several paths in the framework search paths settings.  I want to try deleting them, but I'm worried I'll wreck something else, since at this point I'm beyond where I really know what anything actually means; I'm just pressing buttons and keeping my fingers crossed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it did turn out to be one of the Framework Search Paths.  I'm not sure which ones I deleted, and I'm not sure which one was responsible, but if you're having this issue and clearing the Library and Header Search Paths haven't worked, try the Framework.

Comment: That's a great tip from a couple years ago - thanks!  Saved me hours.

Comment: Really you should "tick" your own answer there, JD

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at this question [‘ld: warning: directory not found for option’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option) it might be what you're looking for :)