# Library not found for -lwebsockets

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x

I am trying to integrate custom library to a cocos2dx project. The project builds before giving a macho-o-linker error.

Comment: This other similar stackoverflow answer may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706348/apple-mach-o-linker-errors-and-i-dont-know-what-to-do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706348/apple-mach-o-linker-errors-and-i-dont-know-what-to-do)